# Как вставить массив в базу данных в SQLite3?

Tags: php, sqlite, sqlite3

Подскажите как вставить разом большой массив в базу данных?

```
$db = new SQLite3("database.db");
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, message TEXT, user_id INT(10), time INT(10))");
$data = [
  ['user_id' => 12, mesages => 'Тест', time => 1601055394728],
  ['user_id' => 14, mesages => 'Тест', time => 1601055394728],
  ['user_id' => 32, mesages => 'Тест', time => 1601055394728],
  ['user_id' => 14, mesages => 'Тест', time => 1601055394728],
  ['user_id' => 41, mesages => 'Тест', time => 1601055394728],
  // ... 1000 записей
];
$db->exec("INSERT INTO messages(id, message, user_id, time) VALUES('........')");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57349614/7485582

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев, там не php. Подскажите как можно на php такое сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите ещё здесь https://stackoverflow.com/q/1176352/7485582. Насколько я понял, для многострочной ставки нужна свежая версия SQLite (>= 3.7.11). Ну и по ссылке другая библиотека используется.

Answer (score 1):

Можете посмотреть и почитать примеры с англоязычной [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database) - там есть также и ссылка на официальную документацию [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html). Лучше будет использовать foreach и вставить записи одна за другой чем городить огород с select/union или строкой со значениями так как там сказано что выигрыша от этого нет.

Comment: Это получается каждый цикл `foreach` он будет обращаться к файлу и делать по одной записи? По идее можно так. А это не скажется на скорости и еще хуже на жесткий диск, или это как то по другому работает? просто с SQLite впервые столкнулся, пока не понятно как он работает

Comment: Открываете файл когда получаете массив массивов данных, делаете вставку через exec для каждой записи в массиве, и закрываете файл.

Comment: ух ты, сейчас протестил вставку в цикле, на вставку всего простых 500 записей, целую минуту запрос отправлялся, я даже боюсь 100 тысяч записей отправлять)) А вообще существует какой то обходной вариант?

Comment: А вы попробуйте завернуть все вставки в транзакцию. Перед первым инстертом сделайте запрос `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, а после инсертов `COMMIT`. Это неплохо ускоряет множественную вставку, но если хотя бы в одной вставке произойдет ошибка, в базу не запишется ни одна запись из транзакции

Comment: SQLite на то и «лайтовый» что не настолько оптимизирован как другие движки. Если вам нужна производительность, то рекомендую использовать PostgreSQL либо MySQL. Если же хотите посмотреть примеры оптимизации запросов и самой БД, смотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite)